# Error in Firefox for lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I have a lightning component that is working fine in chrome but In firefox, it's giving an error.
What could be the possible reason for that?

Error:
**TypeError: Action failed: c:OrderCreation$controller$parentFieldChange [component.find(...) is undefined]**

Error is in **component.find("parentField").get("v.value");**

JS:

```
parentFieldChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('>>> parentFieldChange... '+component.find("parentField"));
        var controllerValue = component.find("parentField").get("v.value");// We can also use event.getSource().get("v.value")
        console.log('>>> parentFieldChange 111... ');
        var pickListMap = component.get("v.pickListMap");
        
        if (controllerValue != '--- None ---') {
            //get child picklist value
            var childValues = pickListMap[controllerValue];
            var childValueList = [];
            childValueList.push('--- None ---');
            for (var i = 0; i < childValues.length; i++) {
                childValueList.push(childValues[i]);
            }
            // set the child list
            component.set("v.childList", childValueList);
            
            if(childValues.length > 0){
                component.set("v.disabledChildField" , false);  
            }else{
                component.set("v.disabledChildField" , true); 
            }
            
        } else {
            component.set("v.childList", ['--- None ---']);
            component.set("v.disabledChildField" , true);
        }
    }
```

Component:

```
    <div class="slds-form_horizontal" aura:id="totalAmountId">
                                            <lightning:select name="parentField" aura:id="parentField"
                                                              value="{!v.parentValue}"
                                                              label="{!v.parentFieldLabel}">
                                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.parentList}" var="value">
                                                    <option value="{!value}" selected="{!value == v.b2bvalue}">{!value}</option>
                                                </aura:iteration>
                                            </lightning:select>
                                        </div>

<div class="slds-form_horizontal">
                                    <lightning:select name="childField" 
                                                      value="{!v.childValue}"
                                                      label="{!v.childFieldLabel}"
                                                      disabled="{!v.disabledChildField}"
                                                      onchange="{!c.onShippingMethodChange}">
                                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.childList}" var="value">
                                            <option value="{!value}">{!value}</option>
                                        </aura:iteration>
                                    </lightning:select>
                                </div>
```

Comment: What is the behavior if you use `event.getSource().get("v.value")` (mentioned in the code comment)?

Comment: I see your `aura:id` and `name` for `lightning:select` is same `(parentField)`, can you try changing the name. Not sure if that would help.

Comment: How is parentFieldChange function getting triggered?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava It's an event handler which is fired from Child Component

Comment: @arut I get the undefined value using event.getSource().get("v.value")